# Insert into point column with ST_GeomFromText column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, insert, spatial, point

I have this MySQL table, only column that matters is `location` here

```
| user_details | 

CREATE TABLE `user_details` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` point NOT NULL /*!80003 SRID 4326 */,
  `region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
  SPATIAL KEY `user_details_location` (`location`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

The location column is supposed to only support 4326 SRID points, but when i try to do an insert in it using

```
INSERT INTO `user_details` 
            (`id`,`userId`,`location`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) 
    VALUES (1, 1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 4326),NOW(),NOW());
```

it says

> Column 'location' cannot be null

If i call ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 0) instead of ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 4326) it says

```
The SRID of the geometry does not match the SRID of the column 'location'. The SRID of the geometry is 0, but the SRID of the column is 4326. Consider changing the SRID of the geometry or the SRID property of the column.
```

The problem is when I set the 4326 in the ST_GeomFromText function.
I'm using MySQL 8.

Comment: 5 column names and 4 value?

Comment: DEFAULT  ..  ? .. ?..  ..

Comment: Ok made the corrections, still any ideas on why it says `location cannot be null` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem was that i had a before insert trigger (forgot all about it) that was checking the SRID and if it was not 4326 it would force it to be 4326, problem was that it was doing it incorrectly, so just changed the trigger to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Does Every row in your Table has a location??
If not, then don't use "not null" character for that column.